# TSQL for xml add schema attribute to root node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, root

My situation is this (simplified):

```
DECLARE @period XML = (
SELECT
'2012' 'period'
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT ('survey'))

DECLARE @persons XML = (
SELECT
Person.Name 'users/person'
FROM Person
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT ('company'))

SET @persons.modify('insert sql:variable("@period") as first into (/company)[1]')
SELECT @persons
```

Which gives me a XML like this:

```
<company>
  <survey>
    <period>2012</period>
  </survey>
  <users>
    <person>Dubach</person>
  </users>
  <users>
    <person>Pletscher</person>
  </users>
  ...
```

Now I need to add a XML-schema to the root node like this:

```
<company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mydomain.com/xmlns/bla/blabla/myschema.xsd" xmlns="http://www.mydomain.com/xmlns/bla/blabla">
  <survey>
    <period>2012</period>
  </survey>
  <users>
    <person>Dubach</person>
  </users>
  <users>
    <person>Pletscher</person>
  </users>
  ...
```

[Microsoft says I have to use **WITH XMLNAMESPACES**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) before the SELECT statement but that does not work in my case.

How can I add these xmlnamespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to add all the namespaces here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/536781/1306012

Obvious it's not very "nice" style but in my case it works and I haven't found another working solution yet.

**SOLUTION**

```
DECLARE @period XML = (
SELECT
'2012' 'period'
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT ('survey'))

DECLARE @persons XML = (
SELECT
Person.Name 'users/person'
FROM Person
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT ('company'))

SET @persons.modify('insert sql:variable("@period") as first into (/company)[1]')

-- SOLUTION
SET @persons = replace(cast(@persons as varchar(max)), '<company>', '<company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mydomain.com/xmlns/bla/blabla/myschema.xsd" xmlns="">')


SELECT @persons
```

Answer (score 4):

Split the declare from the select, then use `with xmlnamespaces` as [described](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

```
DECLARE @persons XML 

;with xmlnamespaces (
    'http://www.mydomain.com/xmlns/bla/blabla' as ns,
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi
)
select @persons = (
    select
        Person.Name as 'ns:users/person' 
        FROM Person 
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT ('company')
)

set @persons.modify('insert ( attribute xsi:schemaLocation {"http://www.mydomain.com/xmlns/bla/blabla/myschema.xsd"}) into (/company)[1]')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works for one namespace. How can I add three namespaces as descripted in my post?

Comment: Thanks, how can I change the "schemaLocation" prefix? I found that I can use "DEFAULT" for the default "xmlns" but how can I create the "xsi:schemaLocation" ?

Comment: Using a `modify`... see above

Comment: The attribute does not appear in my case. At the moment I can't see the problem. I found another solution. See my answer.