# SQL Server FOR XML PATH namespace declaration on root element

Tags: sql, xml, namespaces, sql-server-2012

I'm using a FOR XML PATH query to generate a sitemap from our database and I need to declare a namespace that has a different name than the default:

(see xsi:schemaLocation below)

```
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

How can this be done using :

```
;with xmlnamespaces( default 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9',
                'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi,
                'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
        http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd' --as "xsi:schemaLocation"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution here: [TSQL for xml add schema attribute to root node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726426/tsql-for-xml-add-schema-attribute-to-root-node)

Essentially, I went with this:

```
DECLARE @siteMapXml XML 

SELECT @siteMapXml = (
SELECT 
   s.Dns + '/SomeSection' loc,
   Convert(char(10), GetDate() - 7, 126) as lastmod,
   'weekly' as changefreq,
   0.9 as priority
FROM 
    ThisTable s
WHERE 
    s.Id= 1234
FOR XML PATH ('url'), ROOT ('urlset'))

set @siteMapXml.modify('insert ( attribute xsi:schemaLocation {"http://www.mydomain.com/xmlns/bla/blabla/myschema.xsd"}) into (/urlset)[1]')

select @siteMapXml
```